# passing contents of a list to different functions

Tags: python

I have a list like the following,

```
plist = [[('s', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0]),
          ('aa', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0])],
        [('m', [0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.0]),
         ('ih', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0])],
         [('k', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0]),
          ('l', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0]),
          ('eh', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
          ('k', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])],
         [('t', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0]),
          ('aa', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])],
         [('n', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0]),
          ('ih', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]),
          ('t', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])],
         [('g', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0]),
          ('eh', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
          ('l', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0])],
         [('v', [0.3, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0]),
          ('ae', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0])],
         [('n', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0]),
          ('ih', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0])],
         [('k', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
          ('aa', [0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])],
         [('p', [0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0]),
          ('l', [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0])],
         [('k', [0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0])]]
```

This list is generated from a function. I need to pass the values from the list to different functions. Since there are 5 values inside each inner list therefore I have 5 functions. Now I have to use the values in these functions like the following,

```
def lips_part_bezier(u_value) :
    """ Calculating sampling points using rational bezier curve equation"""
    p0 = 0.0 (1st value of 's')
    p3 = 0.0 (1st value of 'aa')
    p1 = p0
    p2 = p3     
    u = u_value

    p_u = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * 0.7 + 3 * u * math.pow(1 - u, 2) * 0.23 \
        + 3 * (1 - u) * math.pow(u, 2) * 0.1 + math.pow(u, 3) * 0.52

    p_u = p_u * w

    d = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * w + 3 * u * w * math.pow(1 - u, 2) + 3 * (1 - u) * w * math.pow(u, 2) + math.pow(u, 3) * w

    p_u = p_u / d

    #print "p(u) = ", p_u
    return p_u
```

The u_value is passed from another function. There are other functions with the same operation. The second function takes the second values of 's' and 'aa' and so on. This is the first iteration. In the next iteration, p0 in all the functions is the previous p1 and p1 would be the next values from the list. This continues till there are no values left in the list. Also, the list is generated in another function. Being a beginner this looks a bit complicated for me. Thank you.

Comment: don't you need two more parameters in the function to receive values for p0 and p3?

Comment: I suggest you strip down your example to something simpler that still shows your problem. The exact inner workings of `lips_part_bezier` maybe aren't as important (*shrug*)?

Comment: @ F.C. yes I need to pass the p values in the function and thats exactly what my question is.

Comment: @hochi I had asked the same question in a different post earlier with a simple example but I was asked to modify it with the actual code and no one replied after that. Then I posted the question again.

Comment: @zingy: Oh ... ok, I understand that this is demotivating :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you modify the function that generates `plist` so that it returns a dict with a string value as a key and a list as value, or write a new function if you don't have an opportunity of modification. This way, besides `u_value` you can pass the dict and iteration number as arguments to all your functions in the order you want and refer to them like, e.g. `p0 = coefs['s'][iter_num]`.

Comment: I don't need to pass the iteration number because the code iterates according to the number of items in the list. But yes I have to make sure what values it takes as p0 and p1 in each iteration from the list. That is what I am confused about how to pass them to the function.